# Configure .local for vhost High Sierra 10.13.2

Tags: macos

Following this [guide](https://mallinson.ca/osx-web-development/) can't access to site with .local

When try to ping home.local say `ping: cannot resolve home.local: Unknown host` but have this folder in /www

I'm do everything from guide but not working for me.

Comment: is "home" the name you gave to the computer in the "system preferences | sharing" panel?

Comment: No, "home" is folder in /www

Comment: it should work ONLY if you installed dnsmasq. Once it's installed and working it will make all the .local names refer to 127.0.0.1 (that is localhost). Afterwards the rules in the vhosts file will use the name you use for the host to select the proper directory. So, no dnsmasq working, no access to the local webserver